# All users path?

Tags: c++, winapi, path

In C# I can do the following:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE"));
```

Which will get me the path to the all users profile.

In C++ I can use the SHGetFolderPath, but it does not seem to have a CSLID for all users.
Is there an equlivant function that I can blow the %ALLUSERSPROFILE% out to its path value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265(VS.85).aspx) to expand the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` string. This method is part of `Kernel32.dll`.

Comment: I ponder on why this was downvoted. It would be great if there were some elaboration so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Downvote as there are [better more direct ways to get the correct path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1902520/588306) (especially as [there is no "all users profile" folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1902544/588306)). Further to this, environment variables can be changed be the calling application. Whether this is good or not is up to you.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`. Or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28VS.85%29.aspx) since Vista with `FOLDERID_ProgramData`.

Alternatively, use the .NET native `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`

Comment: CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA returns C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data on my XP machine whereas ALLUSERSPROFILE points to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.  Is ALLUSERSPROFILE always the parent of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA?

Comment: `ALLUSERSPROFILE` is `All Users\Application Data` on WinXP. And it is equal to `C:\ProgramData` on Vista.

Comment: Good point; you can't assume that there is such a thing as "**the** directory that holds the entire 'all users' profile", or at least I'm not aware of any documentation which states that.

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes, you should be able to use `SHGetFolderPath` with one of the `CSIDL_COMMON_...` values (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a complete list) to get the subdirectory of the all users' path that you're interested in.  (For Windows Vista and above, you can use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with one of the `FOLDERID_Public...` values; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584%28VS.85%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in certain security situations that folder might not even be a real folder. There not being a CSIDL_ for it is always a strong hint that you're off the beaten path.

Are you sure you're not better off with _APPDATA?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getenv` CRT function to get the value of the ALLUSERSPROFILE environment variable in much the same way as you are for C#.